# When I make a clone of my SD, the resulting image has ethernet problems

Tags: sd-card, pi-3b+, ethernet, ubuntu, server

First of all, I'm working with Ubuntu Server 18.04, on a Raspberry Pi 3b+.

I'm running a server with Nodejs and MongoDB. Everything works perfect. The problem comes when I want to clone the SD into another, in order to not have to repeat all the process in the new SD. However, when I do it, the clone (new) system has ethernet problems. For example, when I do

```
ifconfig
```

eth0 does not appear, unlike in the original image. For what I've read, it seems to be a problem with the MAC address, but I don't know how to solve it.
Is there any way to make a clone in a proper way without losing the ethernet connection?
Thanks

Comment: What does `ls /sys/class/net/` show? For that matter what does `ip a` show on the working system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `netplan` folder try deleting or commenting in your `.yaml` file the lines related to the MAC info:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses: [yourIP/24]            
            gateway4: yourGateway
        match:  #Comment or delete
            macaddress: yourMacAddress #Comment or delete
        set-name: yourNetName  #Comment or delete
```

Apply your `netplan` with `sudo netplan apply` make a reboot and check `ifconfig`.